# Is there a way to get the Log of Kryonet?

Tags: java, kryonet

I want to get the Console Log of the Kryonet as String so that i can display it in a TextArea.
Now my question, is there a way to do it?

I'm stuck at this problem..

Any suggestions would be so much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Kryonet documentation](https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/#Logging):

> KryoNet makes use of the low overhead, lightweight [MinLog logging library](http://code.google.com/p/minlog/).

So looking at MinLog, which is [just one source file](https://code.google.com/p/minlog/source/browse/trunk/src/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/Log.java), you just need to extend `Logger` to override the `print` method, and then call

```
Log.setLogger(new DifferentLoggerImplementation());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, gonna try it first before accepting your answer. Thanks in Advance.